# Plancherel measure and dimension

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

I would like to understand what the Plancherel measure is on the dual of a compact group, in more explicit terms than with an implicit definition. Indeed, to the extent of my knowledge it is defined as the only positive Radon measure such that a certain inversion formula holds, namely
$$\int_{\hat{G}} f(\pi)d\mu(\pi) = f(1).$$

What can be said more precisely when a representation is given explicitly? For instance, consider G the group of projective units of a quaternion algebra. For a ramified place v the group is compact so that the representation is finite dimensional. Do we have that
$$\mu(\pi_v) = \dim(\pi_v)^{-1},$$

as in the finite case, or something similar? Are there references constructing from scratch the Plancherel measure and manipulating it?

Comment: I don't think there are finite-dimensional unitary representations for a connected reductive group other than the trivial one.

Comment: @Zero I modified the question to talk about compact groups, I am interested in this case and want to know if the same relation than for finite groups hold or not.

Comment: @Zero, it depends on the ground field!  For the reals, there are probably lots.  For the $p$-adics, a torus can have some, but a *semisimple* group has none.

Comment: @LSpice What about representations of quaternion algebras at ramified places?

Comment: @TheStudent, quaternion algebras (assuming you mean their multiplicative groups) aren't semisimple; but you are right, that even their unit groups (or adjoint quotients) have non-trivial, finite-dimensional representations.  I should have specified 'non-compact' for my $p$-adic claim.

Comment: @LSpice Sorry for the lack of details, I modified the question to match this requirement, and these are exactly the representations I am interested in!

Comment: The compact-group Plancherel formula is a general thing; it doesn't matter whether the group comes from an algebraic or Lie group, or in any other way, but is purely topological.  I think you mean $\mu(\pi) = \dim(\pi)$ (no inverse).